# Indonesian having Japan Student Visa (Language School) Unable to Apply for S.Korea Tourist Visa in Japan

Tags: visas, japan, south-korea, indonesian-citizens

My friend from Indonesia has stayed in Japan for 1,5 years on student visa for language school and she recently planned a vacation with her classmates to South Korea in September.
They already bought the tickets and booked hotels for their visit since she saw no problem in visa application after some research on the internet.

Turns out, when she tried to apply for SK Visa, she got rejected for the reason that she hasn't fulfilled the "2 year stay" requirement for her to be able to apply for SK tourist visa in Japan (which only got applied this year, they said). She had contacted each country's embassies and they all said for her to go back to Indonesia and apply for SK visa there which isn't an option for her at the moment.

Is there any way she could apply for a South Korean Visa in Japan?

Thank you.

Comment: Stay for another 0.5 years.

Comment: What do you think we could say that would override what she's already been officially told by South Korea?

Comment: As I don't have a ton of knowledge of this myself, I am just trying to seek for alternative if there's any possibility for her to gain the visa Japan since I've read about students being able to gain their visa in Japan (although they're university students instead of just language school students). Either way, thank you for responding.

Comment: I would check with Indonesian embassy. Maybe you can apply remotely (possibly using a family member to deliver the passport, or maybe using a "visa facilitator" [aka travel agency way]).